# Text node not being identified by DOMParser (javascript)

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I ran in quite an unusual problem. If necessary, for a better understanding of the big picture, please refer to my last post, [Unable to retrieve a sub-NodeList from a NodeList in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483426/unable-to-retrieve-a-sub-nodelist-from-a-nodelist-in-javascript/).

Well, that works now, but when I tried to parse a different XML string using basically the same method, the resulting NodeList won't include any text nodes. Instead of the formatted XML, I'll post part of the string I'm trying to parse into a NodeList:

```
<clients><client><code>1111</code><crm>2222</crm><company><name>FOO</name><enterprise>BAR</enterprise><cnpj>XXX</cnpj></company></client></clients>
```

Please notice that those aren't the actual values to the nodes, but the parent node client follows this scructure (it's way abridged though).

So, for testing purposes, I ended up resorting to the following code in order to see if the list is being properly created:

```
function parseClientsXML(xmlString, filter){
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
    var clients = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(filter);

    for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++){
        var client = clients[i].childNodes;
        for (var j = 0; j < client.length; j++){
            var node = client[j];
            $('#div_clients').append("Node index: " + i + " - Type: " + node.nodeType + " - Name: " + node.nodeName + "<br>");
        }
    }
```

calling the function:

```
parseXML(theString, "clients");
```

The result I expected was something like:

```
Node index: 0 - Type: 1 - Name: client
Node index: 1 - Type: 1 - Name: code
Node index: 2 - Type: 3 - Name: #text
Node index: 3 - Type: 1 - Name: crm
Node index: 4 - Type: 3 - Name: #text
```

And so on. Using a string parsed from the XML from my other post as "theString", it works fine. But the output for the string in this post one goes like this:

```
Node index: 0 - Type: 1 - Name: client
Node index: 1 - Type: 1 - Name: code
Node index: 2 - Type: 1 - Name: crm
Node index: 3 - Type: 1 - Name: company
Node index: 4 - Type: 1 - Name: name
...
```

I've been working on this all day but couldn't figure out a solution. The input string is exactly as the one I posted above (well, not exactly, but it's close). Any ideas?

Comment: Going to try and figure this out tomorrow if no one else does, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to your problem as promised.

```
function parseClientsXML(xmlString, filter) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

    (function output(node, filter) {
        var child;
        var children = node.childNodes.length;

        if (filter === "") {
            $('#div_clients').append(node.nodeType + " : " + node.nodeName + "<br>");
        } else {
            filter = node.nodeName === filter ? "" : filter;
        }

        for (child = 0; child < children; child += 1) {
            output(node.childNodes[child], filter);
        }
    }(xmlDoc, filter));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try it out later and give you some feedback ASAP! =)

Comment: It worked perfectly Ryan, thank you. Your code is quite understandable, BTW, but would you have any idea why mine won't work?

Comment: Glad I could help. So getElementsByTagName will go through the tree looking for any nodes with a tag name of "client" and return them. Your code then gets the child nodes of node(s) returned. The child nodes of client have the tag names: "code", "crm", and "company" (hence why you were only getting those outputted). Your code does not go any deeper in the tree. My solution will continue searching the tree for more child nodes (child nodes of child nodes - if that makes sense). This tutorial on W3C may help you better understand http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp

Comment: Oh I get it, and the previous XML worked since the nodetree doesn't have nodes that are "child nodes of child nodes" (if THAT makes sense =p). Thank you very much, Ryan, I've already worked on your code and now I'm able to do pretty much everything I've planned from the beginning.